How to use BringIntoViewRequester in Jetpack Compose? Why does my version not work? or should I use something else?
Short version:
I am trying to create a screen in my app, where there are many text fields in a column, and I want to implement the functionality: when i click on the text field, the keyboard pops up and if the keyboard is obscuring the text field, the screen would scroll appropriately so that the text field is seen above the keyboard. Everything I have attempted does not seem to work. Any idea how to do this?
Extended version:
I have tried BringIntoViewRequester as is suggested in all the tutorials which I found but this does not seem to work for me for some reason. below is the main activity and the used composables, since I dont know where I went wrong (I simplified as best I could). Any and all guidance would be really appreciated!
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MyTestApplicationTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                        MainContent(
                            inputOne = "Android",
                            inputOneChange = { /*Nothing*/ },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainContent(
    inputOne: String,
    inputOneChange: (String) -> Unit,
    scrollableState: ScrollState = rememberScrollState()
) {

    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(scrollableState),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        repeat(6) { PlaceholderCard() }

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
                .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester),
        ) {
            Column {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 16.dp), text = "Please fill something in")
                TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    placeholder = { Text("Some input") },
                    value = inputOne,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = inputOneChange,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() })
                )
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                    onClick = { /*Nothing*/ }) {
                    Text("Click")
                }
            }
        }

        repeat(10) { PlaceholderCard() }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun PlaceholderCard() {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
    ) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp), text = "Placeholder")
    }
}

